# file_put_contents("cache_folder_path_which_is_not_present"): failed to open stream: No such file or {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):

Tags: laravel

Note this question might not be according to community guidelines but I have searched a lot for this issue only then I am posting here. No online solution worked. Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

- Laravel Version: 5.8
- PHP Version: 7.2

This use case is really strange. It never occurs on all the networks but on some specific networks only. 
I have deployed my application in the production environment and for most of the users, it is working fine but I have a specific user, who reported an issue with application behavior on their home wifi. Following is the list where the app is working fine and where it is not.

```
At office 
On Wifi : Working fine
On Mobile data: Working Fine

At home
On Wifi : Not working
On Mobile Data: Working Fine
```

When at his home wifi he made a request, There is an error log generated Screenshot attached.  When in the directory I tried to look for that file, the file is not present.

I have tried all the solutions, like

```
php artisan cache:clear, 
php artisan config:clear, 
composer dump-autoload
```

Also

```
Permission 775 to folder
```

and

```
permission of folder to www:data group and user
```

I am unable to thin, what I can do to at least go in the right direction. Any kind of suggestions or help is appreciated so that I can go in the right direction to look for this issue.

Mind it the issue is only on some specific wifi network. In the same region, other users are not facing this issue one or two users reported this issue but very rare most of the time it is working fine.

**Stack Trace from the error log**

```
[2020-02-04 13:46:50] local.ERROR: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/storage/framework/cache/data/a0/64/a0642963df08e4b8b653718c4a130bcf6864f1a5): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/storage/framework/cache/data/a0/64/a0642963df08e4b8b653718c4a130bcf6864f1a5): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122)
[stacktrace]

\#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/a...', 122, Array)

\#1 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122): file_put_contents('/var/www/html/a...', '1580824070i:158...', 2)

\#2 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php(65): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/a...', '1580824070i:158...', true)

\#3 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(211): Illuminate\\Cache\\FileStore->put('b67cb1918fdc45a...', 1580824070, 60)

\#4 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(316): Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository->put('b67cb1918fdc45a...', 1580824070, 60)

\#5 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php(60): Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository->add('b67cb1918fdc45a...', 1580824070, 60)

\#6 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(56): Illuminate\\Cache\\RateLimiter->hit('b67cb1918fdc45a...', 60)

\#7 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 60, '1')

\#8 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#9 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#10 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

\#11 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#12 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))

\#13 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#14 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#15 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#16 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#17 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

\#18 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#19 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#20 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

\#21 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#22 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#23 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

\#24 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#25 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#26 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

\#27 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#28 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#29 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

\#30 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#31 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#32 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

\#33 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

\#34 /var/www/html/myapp.serverurl.com/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
\#35 {main}
"}
```

**Updated:**

When I changed the cache driver from file to array, it started working fine on the same networks for which it was causing the error.

Comment: There's no screenshot attached. Also don't attach a screenshot just copy-paste the stack trace

Comment: @apokryfos, okay I have added the stack trace please have a look at it.

Comment: Is the issue reproducible with all browsers on all machines within the same wireless network? This issue *might* occur when the server gets hit with 2 identical requests from the same source at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error because of wrong permission rights on storage/framework/cache/data directory. It was under root instead of www-data.